# Save weights for Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save the weights of a simple finetuned BERT model using

```
model.save_weights('saved_model')
```

However the model weights are 1.2 Gi. But this seems wrong as the model summary displayed a filesize of 417Mb

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 bert (TFBertMainLayer)      multiple                  109482240 
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 109482240 (417.64 MB)
Trainable params: 109482240 (417.64 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

Am I forgetting something? Currently using Tensorflow 2.15.0-post1.

Comment: The optimizer also has parameters that were saved...